# Can a posting from a facebook app to a users timeline contain images?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cordova, android-simple-facebook

I am using facebook-cordova -> "Simple Facebook" -> Facebook SDK -> Graph API from an android app and an IOS app.

The functions I use in facebook-cordova to do the actual postings are named .feed() and .share(). They seems to be interchangeable on android i.e. result in the same graph api call in the other end.

What I need is to add images to a posting, preferrably by url.

(I have already managed to do postings without images, using app key and access token etc),

When glancing the facebook SDK for android, it seems there is no obvious way to add images to a status message.

On the other hand, it *is* possible, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to post a photo:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/photos

Of course the same rules apply to the message parameter, no prefilling is allowed, the value must be 100% user generated.

How to do this with Cordova should be explained here: [Phonegap/Cordova Upload photo to graph.facebook - requires upload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232497/phonegap-cordova-upload-photo-to-graph-facebook-requires-upload-file)

Remember that every photo in your profile is in an album: https://www.facebook.com//photos_albums

Afaik you can upload photos to every album except for the profile pictures.

Comment: Will that photo be added to an album?

Comment: it will get added to an App Album, but i think you can also use an Album ID to post: /album-id/photos

Comment: Oh, but I cannot use a solution where the user will find the image in an album. It should only be added to the message.

Comment: why would you need to find an image in an album? you´re only talking about uploading a new one, right?

Comment: I think I regret the formulation "find an image"

Comment: yes, the uploaded image will automatically get added to an app album if you don´t specify another album to upload it to

Comment: Ah, I got you right then, and if that is possible, I don´t want that

Comment: i´ve added some more info for clarification in my answer